# Can you survive the Hardcore Spike in Candy box 2 thats at the end of the game?

Tags: candy-box-2

I "cheated" on "the computer" for a bunch of Pains au chocolat.Then I traded a bunch of them in at the wishing well and got 5200 health.I had enchanted knight armor, unicorn horn, and my inventory was full except for one slot.I tried the "Hardcore level" in "the Arena" and the second I touched a spike , I died.Is it possible to survive these?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is meant to be impossible to survive the spikes, but the actual level is winnable.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be beat. I tried for years. There is no method to win the spike level in arcade. Just like there is no way to get to the end of the pier. Sharks and sea snakes just keep coming. I've tried it for 5 years and can't win these two things.